# jstl, how to fill current request with map

Tags: jstl

I have a map which contain request parameters and their value, which will be used later on the jsp page. I'm usinng jsp page inclusion later and I don't know what exact params would I use

How I suppose, the filling should be implemented:

```
<c:forEach var="theParameter" items="${ parametersMap }" >
    <c:set var="${theParameter.key}" value="${theParameter.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

But I'm getting the error that the 'var' attribute can't use expression

Do you have any ideas about workaround?

EDIT:
Example:

```
parametersMap  = [ 'param1' : 'value1' ; 'param2' : 'value2']
```

as result I would like something like this:

```
<c:set var="param1" value="value1" />
<c:set var="param2" value="value2" />
```

Comment: Are you sure about your code? How do you do like this var="${theParameter.key}" in <c:set ..?

Comment: As I mentioned ... I supposed to use that code .. but it fails to compile due mentioned above error

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
<c:set target="${RequestScope[aNewMap]}" 
             property="${theParameter.key}" value="${theParameter.value}"/>
```

Comment: what is "aNewMap" ? I don't want to set the parameters to new map .. I want to set them into request ...

Comment: See the edited answer. And keep in mind that you can't directly place the map into Request(I dont know what is `request` in your opinion) ofcourse you need a thing to hold the value to travel in request scope

Comment: It means you want to create params as many as you get from the map and set their value? Right?

Comment: I think this is impossible.One way that i think is to keep these value in two different sets (one for key and one for value) OR make another map and set values into it. But they way you are doing is conceptless

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding custom tag, which on java part retrieves the Hashmap object and fill the request (which can be retieved from pageContext)